# To merge values from another dataframe based on partial string match while the matching column is not in same order

Tags: r, dictionary, match

I want to merge one column from `df2` with `df1` by matching `df1$District_name` and `df2$Districts`.
 But the character values in `df1$District_name` and `df2$Districts` are not in the same order and `df1` and `df2` are not of same length.
 The values do not match exactly. `df1` has more rows than `df2`, so the corresponding values for those extra district names should be zero.

```
 df1=data.frame(State_name=c("Maharashtra","Andhra Pradesh","Bihar","Bihar","West Bengal","Gujarat","Gujarat","Assam"),
           District_name=c("Nashik","Chittoor","Madhepura","Kishanganj","Howrah","Gandhinagar","Ahmadabad","Sivasagar"),
           Value1=c(5,3,6,4,4,3,2,4))

df2=data.frame(Districts=c("Nashik","Chitoor","Kishanganj","Madhepur","Sibhasagar","Ahmadabad"),
           FinanceIndex=c(0.20975,0.12187,0.37155,0.66128,0.10918,0.54730))


# df1
      State_name District_name Value1
1    Maharashtra        Nashik      5
2 Andhra Pradesh      Chittoor      3
3          Bihar     Madhepura      6
4          Bihar    Kishanganj      4
5    West Bengal        Howrah      4
6        Gujarat   Gandhinagar      3
7        Gujarat     Ahmadabad      2
8          Assam     Sivasagar      4

# df2
      Districts FinanceIndex
1        Nashik      0.20975
2       Chitoor      0.12187
3    Kishanganj      0.37155
4      Madhepur      0.66128
5    Sibhasagar      0.10918
6     Ahmadabad      0.54730
```

I used match function but due to the spelling differences, I am getting most of them as zero values.

```
index<-match(df1$District_name, df2$Districts)
df1$finindex=df2$FinanceIndex[index]
df1$finindex[is.na(df1$finindex]=0
```

For String matching, I found this function which matches similar phonetic words:

```
library(RecordLinkage)
soundex('Nellore')==soundex('Vellore')
#FALSE
```

The output should be :

```
# df1
     State_name District_name Value1 finindex
1    Maharashtra        Nashik      5  0.20975
2 Andhra Pradesh      Chittoor      3  0.12187
3          Bihar     Madhepura      6  0.66128
4          Bihar    Kishanganj      4  0.37155
5    West Bengal        Howrah      4  0.00000
6        Gujarat   Gandhinagar      3  0.00000
7        Gujarat     Ahmadabad      2  0.54730
8          Assam     Sivasagar      4  0.10918
```

Is there any way these two functions can be used together to solve the problem? Or any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: Spelling differences will be *very* tricky to provide a general solution for

Answer (score 1):

An option is to do a partial match with `stringddist`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
stringdist_left_join(df1, df2, by = c("District_name" = "Districts")) %>%
    select(-Districts)
#      State_name District_name Value1 FinanceIndex
#1    Maharashtra        Nashik      5      0.20975
#2 Andhra Pradesh      Chittoor      3      0.12187
#3          Bihar     Madhepura      6      0.66128
#4          Bihar    Kishanganj      4      0.37155
#5    West Bengal        Howrah      4           NA
#6        Gujarat   Gandhinagar      3           NA
#7        Gujarat     Ahmadabad      2      0.54730
#8          Assam     Sivasagar      4      0.10918
```

Comment: Actually I have all the distict names of India and its confusing names like "Nellore" and "Vellore" or "East Godavari" and "West Godavari".

Comment: @TriparnaPoddar  I showed a method based on the existing examples.  stringdist is based on distance approach to find the similarity